# Selecting / Searching Multiple values from multiple tables , returning only the matched cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dears Please help me pass multiple CPs to find the Process Ids from any one of the following table .

I want to do something like this :

```
declare @CP varchar(30)
Set @CP ='684980','123123','456456'

select ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest where ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno in (@CP)

union all

select ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp where ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp.cpno in (@CP)
```

OR like this

```
select * from XXXX, WWW, MMMM, KKK where CP_NO in ('123123','123321','123567')
```

Using this ,
But here I am unable to pass multiple cp number to get the returns :
Now in this variable i can pass one value like '123123' and can get the results ,
but if i change the query to like in ('123123','123321') instead of =('123123'),
I could not get the results . :(

```
declare @CP varchar(10)
Set @CP ='684980  '

select ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest where ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno = @CP

union all

select ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp where ESuser.tb_pt_additionalcp.cpno = @CP

union all

select ESuser.tb_pt_new_addtionalcp.process_instance_id,         ESuser.tb_pt_new_addtionalcp.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_new_addtionalcp where ESuser.tb_pt_new_addtionalcp.cpno = @CP

union all

select ESuser.tb_pt_vip_service_request.process_instance_id,
ESuser.tb_pt_vip_service_request.cpno
from
    ESuser.tb_pt_vip_service_request where ESuser.tb_pt_vip_service_request.cpno = @CP

union all

select
ESuser.tb_pt_vip_additional_cp.process_instance_id,ESuser.tb_pt_vip_additional_cp.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_vip_additional_cp where ESuser.tb_pt_vip_additional_cp.cpno = @CP

union all

select ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequestbypass.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequestbypass.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequestbypass where ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequestbypass.cpno = @CP
```

Comment: use wild card while using `like` keyword in `SQL`..example `SELECT * FROM table, table1, table2 WHERE column LIKE '%contains%'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a table variable. This is how you can declare it and populate it:

```
DECLARE @CP TABLE (CP_ID VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @CP VALUES ('123123'),('123321'),('123567')
```

And this is how you can use it in your query:

```
SELECT ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.process_instance_id, 
       ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno
FROM ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest 
WHERE ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno IN (SELECT CP_ID FROM @CP)
```

Comment: Dear Thanks but its giving syntax error , saying incorrect syntax near ','. please help .

Comment: @Umair Which part? I think you have not copied the statements correctly.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply , you are amazing .. I am running both the statements together . here is my query . declare atCP table (CP_ID varchar(10))
insert into atCP values ('522452'),('522452'),('522452'),('522452')
 
select ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest where ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno in (select CP_ID from atCP)
 
 
ERROR :
 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @Syed You have not used the @ in `atCP`

Comment: no no dear @ in my code is at , as I was not able to comment :( here is my code  declare @ CP table (CP_ID varchar(10))
insert into @ CP values ('522452'),('522452'),('522452'),('522452')
 
select ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.process_instance_id, ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno
from
ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest where ESuser.tb_pt_servicerequest.cpno in (select CP_ID from @ CP)
 
 
ERROR :
 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @SyedUmairRizvi There is a space between `@` and `CP`.

Comment: I am really sorry for coming back to this again and again .. i places that space just for the remarks as cannot put it next to CP as it does not allow it to , saying cannot tag the user .. Thanks for your patience ... could you test it somewhere .. TY ..

Comment: @SyedUmairRizvi I've already tested the code I've posted and it works fine.

Comment: @SyedUmairRizvi No, this shouldn't be a problem as table variables were introduced with SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Dear I am trying to put this query inside a web form to enter cp no on the form and get the data in the grid .. can you help plz